# In Italian, how is the word "sin" used, as in "ti piace sin troppo bere"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Per essere un giapponese, ti piace **sin** troppo bere il tè con il latte. {jokingly}

In an IM I received from my friend, I saw this unfamiliar word "sin". Curiously enough, I cannot seem to find a relevant entry for this word in any of the mono/bi-lingual dictionaries I use.

Is this a slang term or something? How is it commonly used?

Comment: It's an "apocope" of ["sino"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sino) which is a less common variant of "fino".

Comment: Fat-idiot-kills-the-dogs, now that you know how to look up the word in the dictionaries, do you still need the question to be kept open?

Comment: @DaG I think that an answer is beneficial for future reference, as the relevant information does not seem to come up easily as it stands now.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

[*Sino*](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/sino/) is a variant of [*fino* (adverb)](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/fino2/). Not really common, nowadays; in some cases it is used for euphony: “sino a Fano” instead of “fino a Fano”. In general, *sino* is more literary.

The rules about “troncamento” (apocope) apply the same to *fino* and *sino*:

> fin troppo
>
> sin troppo